# Localizing shiny widget dependencies

Tags: r, jquery-ui, shiny, timepicker

I've created a crude implementation of a `datetimeInput` for Shiny using the jquery-ui [timepicker addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). By itself, the widget works fine, but I run into an issue when the app also contains the standard Shiny `dateInput`. It appears that jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js, which is required for timepicker, modifies datepicker, which is also used by `dateInput`, and it adds a function to datepicker that fails when called with the element generated by `dateInput`.

I could modify the code in jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js to avoid this issue, but that's an inconvenient solution in general. I'd like to know if there is a way to localize my widget's dependency on jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js, so the modifications this script makes to datepicker will only be observable to my widget.

The source code to `datetimeInput` is on [github](https://github.com/OOW/roow). What follows is a demo of the issue.

```
library(devtools)
install_github('roow', 'oow') # install the package with the datetimeInput widget

library(shiny)
library(roow)

test <- function(include_dateInput=FALSE) {
    ui <- fluidPage(
        if (include_dateInput) dateInput('date_input', 'date input', value='1/1/1999') else div(),
        datetimeInput('dtime_input', 'datetime input', min='1/1/1999', max='1/2/1999', value='1/2/1999'),
        textOutput('text_out')
    )
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        output$text_out <- renderText({
            input$dtime_input
        })
    }
    runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
}

test() # datetimeInput works fine
test(TRUE) # datetimeInput doesn't work. If you are in Chrome, you can view the error message with Ctrl+Shit+J
```

In jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js I've included a call to console.log right before the error is encountered to show that is in fact the `dateInput` element that is causing the error. For reference, here is my definition of `datetimeInput` from the source code in the github repository:

```
datetimeInput <- function(inputId, label, value, min=NULL, max=NULL) {
    value <- if (inherits(value, c('POSIXct', 'POSIXlt', 'Date'))) format(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') else value
    tagList(
        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src="roow/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")))
        ,singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href="roow/jquery-ui.css", rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')))
        ,singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src="roow/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")))
        ,singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src="roow/timepicker/timepicker_bindings.js")))
        ,singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href="roow/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css", rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')))
        ,tags$label(class="control-label", `for`=inputId, label)
        ,tags$input(type='text', id=inputId, class='shiny-datetime-input', value=value)
        ,tags$script(sprintf("$(function() {$('#%s').datetimepicker(
            {minDate: '%s', maxDate: '%s', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showButtonPanel: true}
        )})", inputId, min, max))
    )
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327752/how-do-you-load-2-javascript-files-that-could-have-common-variables-between-them